# When to use the expression « Pas besoin de me le dire deux fois ! »

Tags: expressions

> A: Pourquoi ne pas ... en attendant ?
>
> B: ***Pas besoin de me le dire deux fois !*** J’ai hâte de ...

I assume this is an enthusiastic way to express your agreement with a suggestion, but I wonder if it is the equivalent of "Now you’re talking" or "You can say that again".

If so, it is interesting to note that in English you ask for the statement to be repeated, while in French saying it once suffices.

Comment: Not sure *You can say that again* is asking for repeating, it's more of an affirmative form.

Comment: @guillaume31 Oh, literally speaking!

Comment: On a side note, you can use "Pas la peine de (me) le dire deux fois." as a slight variation.

Comment: A moire precise (to me) translation should be "no need to say it twice. I can't wait..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Pas besoin de me le dire deux fois !

although I hear it more often from native speakers in a reported form (*"il n'a pas eu besoin de le dire deux fois"*) than in direct form, usually reflects strong agreement with a request/call to action, or agreement followed by action.

> - Peux-tu aller chercher le dessert dans le frigo ?
>
> - Pas besoin de me le dire deux fois !

*Dire* here is equivalent to *demander*.

*(ne pas) dire deux fois* refers to the possibility that the interlocutor might repeat their request. If they don't need to repeat it, it means that you understood/agree perfectly and will act accordingly.

A slight variant that IMO is more frequent :

> - As-tu vu que la piscine est de nouveau ouverte ?
>
> - Ca, *il ne faut pas* me le dire deux fois ! Je vais tout de suite prendre un abonnement.

In contrast,

> You can say that again! = You said it!
>
> *Tu l'as dit !*
>
> *Je ne te le fais pas dire !*

reflects strong agreement with an assertion or confirmation of a statement - no action is implied.

> Now you're talking
>
> *Là, tu m'intéresses*
>
> *Là, ça devient intéressant*

expresses interest in a suggestion or comment, sometimes as opposed to a previous one deemed less worthy.

Answer (score 0):

That can indeed be used as you guessed, probably most frequently.  In the example you give, I'd translate as "now you're talking" most precisely.

But in a very different tone it could also mean "you don't have to go on and on about it, I get it, I'll do it".

Comment: Yes, I usually expect this expression to be used in a grumbling tone.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not only about agreement.

If someone says "Pas besoin de me le dire deux fois !", I would expect an action to follow. For instance, leaving from an unpleasant place/situation (e.g. stop doing chores), or to a pleasant one (e.g. getting ice cream).

I don't feel like "Now you’re talking" or "You can say that again" express the same idea, but I never encountered them.

"Now you’re talking !" sounds like "Là tu me parles !".

Comment: Now, you're talking! est l'équivalent de *voici qui devient intéressant*,  *ça ça me dit*.

Comment: @Laure I think it is what he meant with "Là tu me parles !" ("ça me parle ce que tu racontes").

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider "Ce n'est pas tombé dans l'oreille d'un sourd", which means that you were pleased to ear that and will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

When you've been told once ! :) Kidding, but you can use it if it is the case. More precisely, you will say "oh ça va, pas la peine de me le dire 2 fois ! J'ai **hâte** de faire la vaisselle". You could then add "Mais j'ai pas 4 bras !".  Dit d'un ton ironique en tirant la langue.
I vote -1 for this answer.

Comment: *"Oh ça va, pas la peine de me le dire 2 fois !"* shows that you're irritated. *"Oh ça va, pas la peine de me le dire 2 fois ! J'ai hâte de faire la vaisselle"* sounds contradictory.